# Why true and false can be strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Unlike many programming languages, `true` and `false` in Javascript can be `'true'` and `'false'`.
Why can they be strings?

Comment: No, they are not. Why do you think so?

Comment: `typeof true == "boolean"`, `typeof 'true' == "string"`???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are not strings. `true` and `false` exists as well, as a primitive boolean type.

What is possible is to convert strings to boolean values.

As can be seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/M6CT2/3/

You only get one true output because it is a non-empty string so it is true, but the boolean is different from the string.

The casting to boolean also returns true when the string is `'false'` because, as mentioned above, it is non-empty.

Comment: Also, 'false' is `true` (as is any nonempty string).

Comment: @RussellZahniser: Clearly `'false' !== true`? Maybe `Boolean('false')` is `true`…

Comment: @Bergi: No, but it converts to `true` in a boolean context, so `if('false')` will be true.

Comment: @RussellZahniser: Yes. The string `'false'` is *truthy* when *in a boolean context*. Your first comment misses that :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ node
> typeof(true) 'boolean'
> typeof(false) 'boolean'
>
```

Comment: Please use `typeof` as an operator, not like a function.